# The sum of $2$ consecutive primes, Are there more $\mod 6=0$?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, statistics, prime-numbers, proof-explanation

All prime numbers greater than $3$ take the form of either $6x+1$ or $6y-1$.

So the only options for the sums of $2$ consecutive primes are:

$(6x+1 + 6y-1) \mod 6=0$

$(6x-1 + 6y+1) \mod 6=0$

$(6x+1 + 6y+1) \mod 6≠0$

$(6x-1 + 6y-1) \mod 6≠0$

According to the limited available options above, the chances for $(6x+1 + 6y-1) \mod 6=0$ or $(6x-1 + 6y+1) \mod 6=0$ to occur are only $50\%$,

However:

Out of the first $200000$ prime numbers, when adding a prime number with the following prime number, $115141$ resulted in $\mod 6=0$ which is about $57.5705...\%$

When I mention "following prime number", I mean it as:  $5+7$  ($7$ is following $5$). another example: $31+37$ ($37$ is following $31$),  another example: $43+47$ ($47$ is following $43$).

Why is it that there are more $\mod 6=0$ occurrences then $\mod 6≠0$ occurrences, when the probability shows that the chances for $\mod 6=0$ is just $50\%$

Am I expecting to see these kind of statistics (margins) continue infinitely? Can it be proven?

Or maybe it is just that my sample test of 200000 is too small, and I should expect a correction in larger samples?

Update: Per @Peter 's comment:

A slight decrease if we continue until [$3⋅10^9+19,3⋅10^9+37$] :

[$79805741,64643795,0.55248180928736247377077071400215505019$]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120324/discussion-on-question-by-isaac-brenig-the-sum-of-2-consecutive-primes-are-th).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a proof, but reasoning to explain why the excess above $50\%$ is around $1/\ln N$, and shrinks very slowly.
Consider numbers near $N$ but only the ones of form $6n\pm1$.  Any random number has a chance of $1/\ln N$ to be prime, but since numbers of the other four remainders are never prime, the chance any one of ours is prime is $$p=\frac3{\ln N}$$
For any prime, assuming a random model for primes, the chance the next prime is opposite remainder, and none of the ones in-between is prime, is
$$p+(1-p)^2p+(1-p)^4p+\ldots\\=\frac p{1-(1-p)^2}\\=\frac1{2-p}$$
When $N=10^6$, this estimate is $56.09\%$.

Comment: You should emphasize that this is only a heuristic. I know this is a very common technique used in analytic number theory, used to make conjectures and usually gives the right results. Those unfamiliar with analytic number theory could think this tries to be a proof. This is not a formal proof. It is, however, a good reason to think that the limit is 50%.

Comment: @jjagmath When you say "obviously diverges", are you reading $p$ as a prime number or as a probability when $N\ge 21$?